# Conditional column based on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI table where fiscal month is stored. I have created an index column and I want a new column based on current month selection. The new column should have the current selection plus two months.

[image: Sample data]

I don't know how to do this.

Comment: If by "column" you mean "calculated column in a data model table", then it's not possible. You must build a measure.

Comment: If it's always two months, then this can be done as a calculated column. But if it's based on a slicer then @RADO is correct that you need a measure in order for it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a calculated column using the following:

```
New Column =
VAR CurrentIdx = 'Table'[Index]
VAR ModOnCurrentIdx =
    MOD ( 'Table'[Index], 11 ) + 2
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        CurrentIdx <= 10, "FM " & FORMAT ( ModOnCurrentIdx, "00" ),
        "FM "
            & FORMAT ( ModOnCurrentIdx - 1, "00" )
    )
```

Which will yield:
[image]
Not the most elegant of solutions but it works!

Hope it helps ;)